# MySql subquery error with delete statement

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm learning sql from these [wikibooks pages](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Exercises/The_warehouse) and I'm trying to answer the last question "Remove all boxes from saturated warehouses" using mysql syntax. The following is what I came up with on my own mainly using previous answers from the same page.

```
delete from Boxes as b
  where b.Warehouse in ( 
        select w.Code
          from ( select *
                    from Warehouses) as w
              where w.Capacity < ( select count(*)
                  from Boxes bb inner join Warehouses ww
                       on bb.Warehouse = ww.Code
                          group by bb.Contents) ) ;
```

The query for this question on the site is generating

```
this solution doesn't work with mysql 5.0.67
 ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'Boxes' for update in FROM clause
```

That's why I'm using multiple sub queries as a way to come around this mysql message. However, I have an error in my query and therefore it's not running.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'as b   where b.Warehouse in ( select w.Code
>   from ( sel' at line 1

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe don't use 5.0.67 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your warehouses table returns from than one columns (since * is used). Replace * with the column u want to get the output from.

Comment: the alias is really well supported as it works for other queries on the same mysql server

Comment: with w.Code instead of *, it still returns :Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as b   where b.Warehouse in ( select w.Code                           from ( sel' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I assume Boxes and Warehouse are tables, you gave Boxes an alias and used it on the Warehouse table, that's probably why it didn't work. Maybe you should try with a query after 'delete from'.

Comment: Warehouse is a field of the Boxes table and Warehouses is a table